# Terminate/skip SysV service during boot

Tags: debian, sysvinit

I seem to remember that since SysV init runs services in a serial (not parallel) fashion, you can kill whatever's currently in the foreground with some key combination -- apparently not ctrl-c/z/d though.

Searching online has not been fruitful.  Does anyone know whether such a key combo really exists (and if so, what is it)?

Comment: I'm not sure about killing it like that, but I do remember you used to be able to put the redhat boot process into an interactive mode where you could say "run", "skip", etc. to each service as it was executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### sysvinit bug

I dug this bit up in a bug that was opened against the `sysvinit` package in a Debian report which would lead me to believe what you're stating is correct. The bug is titled: [sysvinit: Failing to interrupt some script after upgrade](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582442) and it was part of this [Debian Bug report logs - #582442](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582442).

*excerpt*

> since last upgrade (makefile style migration ?) I got strange 
>   behaviour of the boot sequence.
>
> If I interupt some script with ctrl+c, the dependency are lost (not fs
>   mounted, no network, ...).
>   With the previous version this worked.
>
> I interrupt sometimes fsck (when I don't want to wait), now this doesn't
>   work.
>
> Also on my system udev script hang at the end (until there is a
>   timeout). I often hit ctrl+c to avoid waiting the timeout. This now make
>   the system not usable.
>
> If ctrl+c is not supported anymore, it should blocked to avoid this
>   strange behaviour.
>
> Matthieu

Further down in that thread it states that this functionality was supposedly fixed. I did not follow this thread beyond here, so you might want to dig further.

*excerpt*

```
From: Ben Hutchings <ben@decadent.org.uk>
To: 582442-close@bugs.debian.org
Subject: Bug#582442: fixed in sysvinit 2.88dsf-13.1
Date: Sat, 01 Jan 2011 05:47:35 +0000
Source: sysvinit
Source-Version: 2.88dsf-13.1

We believe that the bug you reported is fixed in the latest version of
sysvinit, which is due to be installed in the Debian FTP archive:
```

#### CONCURRENCY=?

I didn't search "much" further but I believe there is a variable in `/etc/init.d/rc` that controls concurrency. When this is enabled it sounds like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> feature is disabled. Setting it to `none` should restore this ability.

```
CONCURRENCY=none
```

I found that mentioned here,  in this Launchpad bug titled: [CONCURRENCY=startpar doesn't work](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/96851).

Comment: I put `CONCURRENCY=none` in `/etc/init.d/rc` and redundantly in `/etc/default/rcS` and ctrl-C works.  TBH I'm not sure that it didn't before as it seems to be an issue with a particular task in `/etc/rc.local` (which still won't stop, but other things do).  However, `CONCURRENCY=none` seems wise if you are prone to do this as it's noted in one of those threads that *"the messages seen on screen are not
in sync with the execution progresses of the jobs"*; hopefully this gives me a better chance of wacking the right mole ;)